# I have problem with my domain on EC2

Tags: magento-1.9, domain

When I browse my domain name **with "www"** it works fine. But **without "www"** it return error **Page not found**.

Currently my server is on EC2. I need expert advice.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add the following code to your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This site can’t be reached error raise for chrom

Comment: domain.com’s server DNS address could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

yes I agree with the  above the given answer and alternatively your domain is mapped , without www. , you can check in the configuration and change as your requirement